# Selective attributes for paths - Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I've got a web page with a [US map](http://www.radiantlifeproductions.com/development/petrocard/emptynewmappage.html)  that has clickable paths that generate a popup, coded with Raphael.js and a paths file containing all the state's paths. I loop through the paths file to create the paths and set the `onClick` and hover functions for the popups.

I have one path that is not a state, it is a border around the misplaced Alaska and Hawaii.  Problem is when I loop through the code, it gets set to fill and `onClick` functions same as the other paths.

I know I need a conditional in there to change attributes for that one path, but I'm not savvy enough to be able to code it correctly.  Maybe access the DOM through node, but I'm not sure how/where.

[Map](http://www.radiantlifeproductions.com/development/petrocard/emptynewmappage.html) created with [this script](http://www.radiantlifeproductions.com/development/petrocard/js/init.js).

paths set with `/js/paths.js`

css is `/css/default.css`

I've searched the archive and gotten close to a solution from info posted there, but I'm banging my head trying to tweak it to work - any help GREATLY appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is called "BD" so you can do something like this or even create a different borderAttributes object and assign different attributes when country == "BD"

```
for (var country in paths) {
    var obj = r.path(paths[country].path);

    if (country != "BD") {
        obj.attr(attributes);
    }

    arr[obj.id] = country;
```